# Fix bad sinusoidal curve fit

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I have two sinusoidal datasets that I am trying to fit.

Code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Define sinusoidal function
def test(x,a,b,c,d):
    return a*np.sin(b*x+c)+d

# Grab data
datos = np.loadtxt('data_12_rot_norm',dtype=float)

# Convert data into vectors
ang = []; fib1 = []; fib2 = []
for i in range(datos.shape[0]):
    ang = np.append(ang,datos[i][0])
    fib1 = np.append(fib1,datos[i][1])
    fib2 = np.append(fib2,datos[i][2])
# Perform the curve fit
param,param_cov = curve_fit(test,ang,fib1) # fib1 is the variable, repeat for fib2

# Print the fitted parameters
print("Sine function coefficients:")
print(param)
print("Covariance of coefficients:")
print(param_cov)

# Plot the data and the fitted curve
plt.scatter(ang,fib1,s=5,color='blue',label='Data') # idem
plt.plot(ang,test(ang, *param),linewidth=1,color='red',label='Fit')
plt.ylim(0,1)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Fit 1:
[image]

Fit 2:
[image]

As you see, both data sets show an obvious sinusoidal behavior, however, the fit is inaccurate accurate. I haven't tried anything beyond deleting one parameter from the function definition, but it solved nothing.

Expected results: A good sinusoidal fit ranging from 0 to 1 that represents the data set, including the shift.

Comment: You could do an FFT and pick out the strongest frequency.

Comment: Unrelated suggestion: numpy reads in the data as a numpy array, so you can easily separate the data as `ang = datos[:,0]`, `fib1 = datos[:,1]`, and `fib2 = datos[:,2]` without any `for` loops. Alternatively, you can use the `unpack=True` option in `np.loadtxt`, which gives `ang, fib1, fib2 = np.loadtxt(filename, unpack=True)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - curve fit producing incorrect fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42169643/python-curve-fit-producing-incorrect-fit)

Comment: @jared thank you for your suggestion. May be unrelated to the question itself but I always forget how to unpack data so I end up with a messy `for` loop.

Comment: Using the unpack option with `np.loadtxt` might be less common, but you should at least get used to slicing since everything you do in numpy will rely on knowing that.

Answer (score 3):

You can 'help' the fit by providing a decent starting point for your fitting parameters (so that the optimization doesn't start too far away from default initialization and then ends up stuck in a local minimum), i.e. providing values to optional argument `p0`. In your case, I would imagine `p0 = (0.4, 4, 0, 0.5)` should do a decent job? (and then `curve_fit(test,ang,fib1, p0=p0)`)

Comment: This suggestion helped me a lot, once I understood the nature of the p0 array. FYI, since you gave me a hint on where to start, the best fit I can get resulted in `p0 = (-0.3,4,0.63,0.5)`. Thank you!